# XSnippet EmailBean error

Tags: java, xpages

I na project I want to use the EmailBean written by  Tony McGuckin, IBM

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter

However I get an error message when I want to loop through a list of people I want to address:

```
for (String person : persons) {
                EmailBean emailBean = new EmailBean();
                emailBean.setSendTo(person);
                emailBean.setSubject("You have been mentioned");
                emailBean.setSenderEmail("pk@mail.com");
                emailBean.setSenderName("PK's app");
                Document mail = null;
                mail = db.createDocument();
                > emailBean.setDocument( mail);
                emailBean.setFieldName("Body");
                emailBean.setBannerHTML("<p>You have been mentioned in a discussion on PK's App:</p>");
                emailBean.setFooterHTML("<p>Kind regards,<br/>PK App<br/></p>");
                emailBean.send();
            }
```

The error message I get resides at the > line:

The method setDocument(DominoDocument) in the type EmailBean is not applicable for the arguments (Document) Comment.java    comments.nsf/Code/Java/org/quintessens/comments line 98 Java Problem

I have tried to cast the Document as a DominoDocument but then I get an error at line

```
emailBean.send();
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mail variable is a Document object. You need to wrap it into a DominoDocument object (the object used as Domino Document datasource)

after your line :

```
mail = db.createDocument();
```

add :

```
DominoDocument wrappedMail = DominoDocument.wrap(db.getFilePath(), mail, null, null, false, null, null);
```

then use it in your email bean :

```
emailBean.setDocument( wrappedMail );
```

But you will have to set something in the "body" field of your document created with this line :

```
mail = db.createDocument();
```

and before wrapping it, because the content of the mail you'll send is taken from this field.

But if you want to send "simple" content, use the class from Ulrich Krause in his comment of the XSnippet page which still give you the possibility to add the content of a field to the email but also let you add "simple" content.

Then remove the following lines in your original code :

```
Document mail = null;
mail = db.createDocument();
emailBean.setDocument( mail);
emailBean.setFieldName("Body");
```

And use this instead :

```
emailBean.addHtml("this is my mail content");
```

You can call this as many times as needed

Comment: I still get an error at emailBean.send() -> 
Unhandled exception type Exception and 
Unhandled exception type IOException. I surrounded the code in a try catch block but get java.lang.NullPointerException in the log

Comment: In Tony original code it was mandatory to use a document with a field in it that already contains the content of you want to send as your email content. 

If you use the class from Ulrich Krause in his comment on the XSnippet webpage, you will be able to send simple content without doing that. I modified my answer with more details

Comment: I decided to use the email class from OpenNTF Domino API instead. That is a bit easier in my case. I also tried Ulrich's class but got similar warnings.

Answer (score 1):

To get the DominoDocument from a Document, a typical (DominoDocument) will not work.
You need to call the wrap method of the DominoDocument.
See the API, http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.html#wrap(java.lang.String, lotus.domino.Document, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)